# Powering peltier tile using 3.7V lipo battery?

Tags: arduino, boost, lipo, peltier

Is it possible power the peltier tile to a reasonable temperature using only a 2500mAh 3.7V lipo battery and DC Boost Converter to boost the output to 12V?
[image]
The peltier tile I'm using is bought here: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10080

I would also be using the same lipo battery to power an arduino to control the peltier tile too.

Comment: Just do the maths and calculate how much current you could produce at 12V (even with 100% efficiency) and compare it to the elements specs.

Comment: The tile takes a max current of 7A, so the battery would have to supply at least 21A. What do you think?

Comment: Short answer. No, even if you could somehow get the >20A needed, 2500mAh capacity would power the circuit for about 10 minutes max.

Comment: @Photon Did you actually read the entire comment you're responding to?

Answer (score 1):

The constrain of using a 2500mAh lipo battery in such application is energy capacity limit of that battery, nothing else. This will severely affect the run time of whatever connected to it.

According to this web (http://multicopter.forestblue.nl/lipo_need_calculator.html), some lipo can be drained at 40C rate. Most lipos can handle continuous discharge at 25C happily. At 25C rate a 2500mAh battery can supply 62.5 Ampere for about two and a half minutes. However I believe this can be true only for high quality lipos.

Now knowing that lipos can handle that much of current, plugging this cell in your circuit which demands only about 20Amps, you will have 7.5 minutes continuous run time.

This time duration can be lengthen if the peltier heat pump runs only intermittently. Having this as the ball park, actual useful time of 2500mAh cell in that application can be judged.